# How should I jump into the Flex-Python Boat

Tags: python, apache-flex, pyamf

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208528

Bruce Eckel talked about using Flex and Python together. Since then, we have had PyAMF and the likes.

It has been almost three years, but googling does not reveal much more than a bunch of articles/comments linking to that article above (or related ones). There is no buzz, no excitement. Not much on SO either.

I am thinking of attempting something using Flex/Python which would require me to be heavily invested in it. What I worry about is that the support system is very weak and activity is almost nonexistent.

I really want to do this. Can anyone direct me towards some useful resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application written in Flex/Flash is server agnostic...and it should be easy to replace the server side language with another one. The client application will consume some web services exposed by the server(REST/SOAP), or it can use as an alternative remote method invocation. The last one is implemented for the most important languages, from what I know.

There are some exceptions..if you want to use messaging the professional solutions are offered mainly by the frameworks build on top of Java.

So if you do not rely heavy on messaging the heavily investment is going to be mainly of the client side, especially if you haven't worked before with the so called "fat" clients. But not on the integration side..it not so complicated.

Regarding useful Flex resources, my suggestion is to take a look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html